# Access static method on generic class

Tags: java, generics, methods, static

I'd like to access a static method on a class, but have that class passed in a generic.

I've done the following:

```
class Base{
  public static String getStaticName(){
    return "Base";
  }
}


class Child extends Base{
  public static String getStaticName(){
    return "Child";
  }
}

class StaticAccessor{
  public static <T extends Base>String getName(Class<T> clazz){
    return T.getStaticName();
  }
}

StaticAccessor.getName() // --> "Base"
```

This will return "Base" but what i'd like is "Child" anybody a suggestion without reflections?

Answer (score 9):

You can't do that without reflection, because the type `T` is erased at runtime (meaning it will be reduced to its lower bound, which is `Base`).

Since you **do** have access to a `Class<T>` you can do it with reflection, however:

```
return (String) clazz.getMethod("getStaticName").invoke(null);
```

Note that I'd consider such code to be code smell and that it is pretty fragile. Could you tell us why you need that?

Comment: Simpler: return clazz.getSimpleName();

Comment: @Nathan: yes, *if* the implementation will always look like that.

Comment: correct. My suggestion works only if the intention of the getStaticName() method is to return the simple (or binary/canonical) name of the class.

Comment: @joachimSauer could you please explain better "...the type `T` is erased at runtime".

Answer (score 0):

If it is OK for you to pass an object instance rather than Class in your static accessor, then, there is a simple and elegant solution:

```
public class Test {

    static class Base {
        public static String getStaticName() { return "Base"; }
        public String myOverridable() { return Base.getStaticName(); };
    }

    static class Child extends Base {
        public static String getStaticName() { return "Child"; }
        @Override
        public String myOverridable() { return Child.getStaticName(); };
    }

    static class StaticAccessor {
        public static <T extends Base>String getName(T instance) {
            return instance.myOverridable();
    }

}


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Base b = new Base();
        Child c = new Child();

        System.out.println(StaticAccessor.getName(b));
        System.out.println(StaticAccessor.getName(c));

    }

}
```

The output is:

```
Base
Child
```

Comment: Yep this is just using polymorphism though to get the Name.  The original example seemed to imply it should work without any Object instances and work just against the Class.  I guess in the example you could just call the getName method on the object instance itself.

Comment: @planetjones No, you cannot call getStaticName() on the instance itself, because it would only return 'Base' in both cases.

Comment: oh sorry I meant to say call the method against the Object i.e. myOverridable() could be called directly against b or c.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this without reflection.

It appears you should be doing is not using static methods.  You are using inheritance but static methods do not follow inheritance rules.